# MySQL convert hex to double

Tags: mysql

Which aproach should be taken in MySQL to convert from HEX (8 Bytes) to a double value?

To convert from HEX to INT I use CONV(hex_value,16,10). But in order to converto to double I've no idea.

```
CREATE FUNCTION HEX2DOUBLE(hex_input TEXT) RETURNS DOUBLE
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE hex_bits VARCHAR(64);

DECLARE sign_bit VARCHAR(1);
DECLARE expoent_bits VARCHAR(11);
DECLARE mantissa_bits VARCHAR(52);

DECLARE i INT;
DECLARE mantissa DOUBLE;
DECLARE expoent INT;
DECLARE result DOUBLE;

SET hex_bits = LPAD(CONV(hex_input, 16, 2), 64, '0');

SET sign_bit = SUBSTR(hex_bits, 1, 1);
SET expoent_bits = SUBSTR(hex_bits, 2, 11);
SET mantissa_bits = SUBSTR(hex_bits, 13, 52);

SET expoent = CONV(expoent_bits, 2, 10)-1023;

SET i = 1;

SET mantissa = 0;
WHILE(i <= 52) DO
    IF SUBSTR(mantissa_bits, i , 1 ) = '1' THEN 
        SET mantissa  =  mantissa +  1/POWER(2, i);        
    END IF;
    SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;

IF(expoent > -1023) THEN
    SET mantissa = mantissa + 1;
END IF;

SET result = POWER(2, expoent) * mantissa;
IF(sign_bit = 1) THEN
    SET result = -1 * result;
END IF;

RETURN result;
END//
```

The above seems to work most of the time. What you guys could say about it? One problem I'm facing is 
SQL Error (1690): DOUBLE value is out of range in pow(2, expoent@7), which I think referes to the line `SET result = POWER(2, expoent) * mantissa;`

Comment: I tried `CAST(CONV(HEX(REVERSE(a.data)), 16, 10) AS DOUBLE)`, but it returns the following error: ERRO 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax. MySQL version is 5.6.17.

Comment: What's the error? And what version of MySQL are you using? (`mysql --version` if you're on Linux).

Comment: Is there anything else I can provide? I'm on Win 7.

Comment: A couple of questions: why are you doing `HEX` and then converting from hex to decimal? `HEX` is going to convert its argument to a series of ASCII hex values. Converting that to a single number isn't very meaningful. MySQL doesn't support `CAST` to `DOUBLE` as it turns out. Also, why do you need to convert the final result to double? Perhaps there's another way to solve your original problem.

Comment: If I do it without the HEX step conversion returns 0. Just to exemplify, an usual value for a.data is like 0290 (it's the output of SUBSTR). It is meaningful for me to convert it to 656 (like the win calc will do). But now, back to the problem: I know there is a double stored in 8 Bytes from a a raw insert, I use SUBSTR to pick that 8 Bytes and then I have to convert it. Have to think different?

Comment: Any suggestion on how to proceed?

Comment: Why are you saying "double?"  8 characters ("bytes") of data stored as hex characters is, at most, a 4-byte integer, since hexadecimal only conveys 4 bits per symbol.  Are you trying to take the 32-bit unsigned integer equivalent of the extracted hex expression (maximum range of values would be 0x00000000 through 0xffffffff) and store it in a column of data type `DOUBLE`?  Or something else?  Why were you using `REVERSE()`?

Comment: Starting from the end... REVERSE is there to change endianess. Actually I'm not storing it, just showing the value in a view. Yes, the range is 0x00000000 through 0xffffffff. Yes, taking the HEX expression from a BLOB field. I'll try to understand this "8 characters ("bytes") of data stored as hex characters is, at most, a 4-byte integer, since hexadecimal only conveys 4 bits per symbol". Well, so it seems double is not a correct way to indicate what a convertion do I need.

Comment: An example: Given 0x3F0042617A9C7BE9, I would like to know which function will return 0.000031012153455238344. As this http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?hexadecimal=3F0042617A9C7BE9

Comment: This problem would have been a lot clearer if you mentioned that your original 8-byte binary was double precision floating point format. ;) Are you operating purely within MySQL or are you using a language around that? You can use bit manipulation functions from MySQL to do the conversion but it would be quite tedious. It would be easier to capture the blob at the program level of you're using some other language around MySQL. MySQL does not have a built-in conversion.

Comment: Sorry for my newbie behavior :( I'm afraid I'll have to to it within MySQL. The scenario around MySQL is the following: From on side there is an app which do the insert in a BLOB. And from another side I'm watching the MySQL. I'm playing with Qt, but just watching the the view with a QSqlTableModel. Could you please give some more words about the bit manipulation strategy?

Comment: See [IEEE754 Double precision 64-bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) for meanings of the bit fields. Look up MySQL bit manipulation for MySQL functions to handle the arithmetic. It will be a tedious conversion.