# MySQL, Avoid DOUBLE value is out of range in POW(2, 1024)

Tags: mysql

I've noted that MySQL returns error for `POW(2, 1024)`, ERROR 1690 (22003): Double value is out of range in POW(2, 1024). How to avoid this error?

I thinking in a very ugly solution:

```
IF (@EXPOENT > 1023) THEN @EXPOENT = 1023;
POW(2, @EXPOENT);
```

This relates to [MySQL convert hex to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836139/mysql-convert-hex-to-double).

Comment: But `POW(2, 1024)` **is** out of range. You want to change out-of-range data to something in range? That seems dangerous; now when you get a result you have no idea if it is correct or not; it could have been out of range.

Comment: I want to avoid the error. Any suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify it using the `LEAST()` function:

```
POW(2, LEAST(@EXPOENT, 1023))
```

Comment: beat me to it! thats how i would do it too! +1