# Convert little endian binary to double

Tags: mysql, select, binary, double, type-conversion

I'm trying to make a simple proof as to how my data has been stored in MySQL/MariaDB. Essentially it is a binary string of little endian which represents the numeric values I recorded in my software.

I am however struggling to use a SELECT case where I am performing the conversion within the select to return the correct results. It generally gives me large numbers with the methods I have currently tried with CAST and CONVERT.

What I have thus far is:

```
SELECT HEX(BINARY(SubString(Data,0,8))) As Data from prop_binary;
```

This correctly returns the binary HEX representation, for example:

```
000000000000F03F
```

This should then correspond to 1 in little endian format. I would prefer to be able to achieve this entirely in MySQL as I plan to use this in a stored procedure.

Comment: Please explain the motivation for doing this? Also this might (is?) platform dependent.

Comment: I have a MEDIUMBLOB which is a binary representation of a numeric array. The array has no delimiter and is simply in packets of 8 bytes (hence the Substring). I'm trying to proof a correct method to convert before working on a stored procedure which will hopefully in the end return the whole array as a table of numerics (doubles).

Comment: Why on Earth are you storing an array as a MEDIUMBLOB?

Comment: Because that's how the software has done so. I have no control over how the software is storing the data. Each record corresponds to a specific step in the software and so the array is stored in a singular row to correspond to the correct foreign key. It works fine if I use languages like C++ to do the conversion but that won't fit with the end goal.

Comment: Okay I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836139/mysql-convert-hex-to-double

This explains how to get past my endianness problem if it is indeed an issue (not sure whether MySQL works in Little-endian yet)... Could you clarify what they mean by tedioussness?

Comment: This is the wrong way to go. It is making a lot (I mean a lot) of assumptions on the encoding of doubles. Is it IEEE 754, something else, ....

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind Ed, I fixed it by implementing the Convert_Hex_2_Double function in the forum http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1703348-MySQL-convert-hex-to-double. Then I implemented Reverse was getting the right values.

Ultimately I ended up with:

```
Select Convert_Hex_2_Double(HEX(Reverse(Binary(Substring(Data,17,8)))) As Data from prop_binary;
```

This returns the correct dataset and proves to me that I can achieve this in MySQL so can move forward to a stored procedure.

Note: Since this is MariaDB, while the function could be created, it needed modifying to remove spaces between function names and their parenthesis which I learned only hours ago from:

http://3.droppdf.com/files/n4agH/learning-mysql-and-mariadb.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be the easiest solution :

```
REVERSE(HEX(REVERSE(UNHEX('000000000000F03F'))))
```

1. convert the hex into binary
2. reverse the string
3. convert it back into hex
4. reverse it a again