# How to convert from little endian hex into double in MySQL5.7

Tags: mysql, endianness

I need to convert `000000000000F03F` from one table into `1.0` (Double) format in another table. Casting and unhex will not yield the desired result. Is there any stored procedure/implementation or method that converts in the following direction in MySQL?

I've seen a similar question, but no answer was provided @ [Convert little endian binary to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571707/convert-little-endian-binary-to-double/78001773#78001773)